# Hover over image won't line up properly with zoomed image

Tags: html, css

Trying to have a 65x65 image enlarge on hover, which it does, but the hover overlay is not centered for any of the icons. Any idea?

[image: Picture]

```css
.overlay{
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #3b5998;
    border-radius:50px;
    margin: 5px;}

.icon{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    width:65px;
    height:60px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <img src="IMG/icon.png">
  <div class="overlay">Name name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is better if you show some code to get an idea.

Comment: edited now, thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be complete. Its recommended to include the full code including hover state.

Comment: I think this is a hover problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of `margin: 5px;` css property in `.overlay` selector to align the overlay with image. Try this code.

```
.icon{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    width:65px;
    height:65px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.icon img {
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay{
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #3b5998;
    border-radius:50%;
    z-index: 2;
    }
.icon:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, keep coding :)

Comment: Could you please accept the answer, by pressing the tick button.